# Duplicating/Mirroring Object breaks the shading

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, shaders, mirror

After duplicating/mirroring one side of my object, the shading gets broken and the texturing is not even whatsoever and I have no idea as to why this is.

I've tried:

- Recalculating the normals
- Applying scale
- Deleting overlapping verts
- Checking for any unnecessary faces
- Backface Culling my material
- Checking the face orientation of the normals
- Deleting any unnecessary Geometrical Data
- Duplicating and rotating the object
- Mirroring the object

Nothing so far has worked, and I have no idea as to why my meshes shading is broken. Any tips/tricks to help fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yTbc5c0g2Rn-PMqOWnKklOttfrz65dip/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you checked any inner face? maybe share your file?

Comment: have you recalculated the normals after applying the scale?

Comment: @moonboots I have; there seemed to be nothing unless I missed something. I also put a link to my file in the post!

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz yes, I've tried that and everything else even after applying scale.

Answer (score 0):

You've shaded smooth, Blender smoothes between the large faces and the adjacent ones (the ones of the bevel), therefore this bad shading. If you want to avoid that, you can simply inset these faces, now their adjacent faces are co-planar, there won't be any smoothing between these insets and the adjacent faces:

[image]

[image]